# Rule in htaccess does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, prestashop-1.6

I try to remove one argument from url using htaccess.
I found in documentation 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

```
# Remove mykey=???
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "(.*(?:^|&))mykey=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$"
RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1?%1%3"
```

But it doesnt work

when I run url 
http://somedomain.com/someurl?p=1&mykey=1&t=1
then url is still the same, maybe prestashop change some thing

```
#START AS4 RULES (Do not remove)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^as4_seositemap.xml$ modules/pm_advancedsearch4/sitemap/seositemap.xml [L]
RewriteRule ^as4_seositemap-([0-9]+).xml$ modules/pm_advancedsearch4/sitemap/seositemap-$1.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^controller=products-comparison [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})?/?s/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*) index.php?fc=module&module=pm_advancedsearch4&controller=advancedsearch4&isolang=$1&id_seo=$2&seo_url=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^isolang=([a-z]{2})&id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*).*p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /%1/s/%2/%3?p=%4 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^isolang=([a-z]{2})&id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /%1/s/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*).*p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /s/%1/%2?p=%3 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_seo=([0-9]+)&seo_url=([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)
RewriteRule ^advancedsearch4.php /s/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#END AS4 RULES

# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

# Remove mykey=???
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))mykey=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%3

#Domain: markoweobuwie.com.pl
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Etag
</IfModule>
FileETag none
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

I will be grateful for help in this theme, because I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: "then url is still the same", you should search for rewrite vs redirect.

Comment: Let's say that I want to redirect 
site http://somewebsite.com/page1?mykey=2 to http://somewebsite.com/page1
I use rule
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)?mykey=2$  $1  [R,L]
but it don't work

Comment: Whar does "it don't work" mean? What do you expect? And what does happen instead?

Comment: when I put in browse link somewebsite.com/page1?mykey=2 urls should change to somewebsite.com/page1, I want to remove parameter mykey and redirect user to new site.

I hoped that rule 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)?mykey=2$ $1 [R,L] 
will be ok, for this behavior, but this rule does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))mykey=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%3
```

already looks good and works for any number of arguments.

It only needs a minor tweaking

- Don't use a relative target URL, e.g. insert a leading slash `/`

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%3
  ```

  or add an appropriate [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive, e.g.

  ```
  RewriteBase /
  ```

  or employ `REQUEST_URI`, which already contains the complete path

  ```
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%3
  ```
- To redirect, you must use a [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%3 [R,L]
  ```

Comment: Thank you Olaf, now it is working well a leading slash / makes a job done.